# Android Fragment load API data

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

During my freetime I am making a basic app. I have a navigation with fragments. The home screen is an activity screen. Now I have the problem that I cannot select the layout where the API data needs to load in. My MainActivity looks like this (I think that the onCreate is enough but copied the whole class):

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.example.myapplication.domain.Joke;
import com.example.myapplication.logic.JokesAPITask;
import com.example.myapplication.logic.JokesAdapter;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.myapplication.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements JokesAPITask.JokeListener{

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;
    private RecyclerView recyclerview;
    private JokesAdapter jokesAdapter;
    private ArrayList<Joke> jokesList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar);
        binding.appBarMain.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = binding.drawerLayout;
        NavigationView navigationView = binding.navView;
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

        recyclerview = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_jokes_top10);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager =
                new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        jokesAdapter = new JokesAdapter(jokesList);
        recyclerview.setAdapter(jokesAdapter);

        String[] params = {
                "https://official-joke-api.appspot.com/random_ten"
        };
        new JokesAPITask(this).execute(params);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }


    @Override
    public void onJokesAvailable(List<Joke> jokes) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onJokesAvailable: aangeroepen");

        this.jokesList.clear();
        this.jokesList.addAll(jokes);
        this.jokesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not implemented navigationView's onItemSelectedListener.
load respective fragment from there and load data from fragment

```
 binding.navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                int id = menuItem.getItemId();
                Intent intent;
                switch (id) {
                    case R.id.menu_home:
                        // your code goes here or you can replace fragment
                        break;
                    case R.id.menu_profile:

                        // your code goes here
                        break;
                    case R.id.menu_logout:
                        // your code goes here
                        break;
                }
                return true
            }
        });
```